# Highcharts -> Style vertical lines in the navigator

Tags: css, highcharts, styling

I try to style these vertical lines in the navigator. Tried all option listed for the navigator in the API: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/navigator

But none of them seem to have an effect. Is there another option to style this?

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide "jsfiddle" your code may i will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to style the navigator's `xAxis`. These options are the ones you are looking for: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.gridLineColor. Check anything that starts `gridLine`

[Here (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/am9wymcj/) I changed vertical lines to be pink.

The relevant part is:

```
navigator: {
    xAxis: {gridLineColor: '#ff0000',},
},
```